# replace multiple lines in a txt file using another file in bash

Tags: bash, replace

I have two files "file1.txt" and "file2.txt" containing the same number of lines.
I want to replace the odd lines of file2.txt by the odd lines of file1.txt.

Example:

file1.txt

```
header1.1
content1.1
header1.2
content1.2
header1.3
content1.3
```

file2.txt:

```
content2.1
header2.2
content2.2
header2.3
content2.3
```

The result I want:

file2.txt:

```
header1.1
content2.1
header1.2
content2.2
header1.3
content2.3
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your example files do not have the same number of lines.

Comment: Your example does not match what you're trying to do as you seem to be missing `header2.1` as the first line of file2.txt. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

This will do it, assuming that `header2.1` should be the first line of `file2.txt`.

```
I=1
paste -d '\n' file1.txt file2.txt | while read line ; do 
  if [ `expr \( $I + 3 \) % 4` -eq 0 ] ; then echo "$line" ; fi 
  if [ `expr  $I % 4` -eq 0 ] ; then echo $line ; fi 
  I=`expr $I + 1`
done
```

I'm using the `paste -d '\n' file1.txt file2.txt` to combine the 2 files into one stream with alternating lines that I then need to extract the correct row numbers. If you note that result of the paste looks something like:

```
[row 1] header1.1
[row 2] header2.1
[row 3] content1.1
[row 4] content2.1
[row 5] header1.2
[row 6] header2.2
[row 7] content1.2
[row 8] content2.2
....
```

It seems you want the odd lines of file1.txt and the even lines of file2.txt. In the combined example, you want row 1 and row 4 for each set of 4 rows.

This takes the line number, adds 3 and checks if that's divisible by 4 with no remainder by using the % (modulus) operator. This will match for row 1, row 5, row 9, etc.

```
expr \( $I + 3 \) % 4
```

This checks that the line number is divisible by 4

```
expr  $I % 4
```

Comment: Using paste with `-d '\n'` is a smart move! Please change `echo $line` into `echo "$line"`. Perhaps also switch to lowercase `i` and the shorter  `((i++))` and `if (($i % 3==0)); then ..`.

Comment: Good catch with `echo "$line"`, I've updated that. I use `$I` rather than `$i` as the old standard was to use capitalized variables in shell scripts and I use `expr` instead of bash's `(( ))` as it will work in any shell so is more generalizable. But I agree that if one were certain to be using bash, `(( ))`is prettier and clearer.